# actualizar valor de span acutomaticamente

Tags: javascript, java, html

Tengo un `span`:

```
<span id="sub-total">0</span>
```

que quiero multiplicar cada vez que arroje un dato con otro `span`, algo así :

```
<span id="sub-total">0</span>
<span id="total">0</span>
```

Esto es lo que he tratado:

```
var multi = sub-total.innerHTML * total.value;
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=multi;
```

lo que quiero es que sea automático el calculo,  ejemplo: si la web arroja un resultado por `subtotal` se multiplique con el total automáticamente. quien pueda ayudarme le agradecería

Comment: Redacta mejor tu pregunta. Visita este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Para esto puedes llamar una función al cargar tu página,

```
  <body onload="multiplicar()">
```

esta función obtendrá los valores de los `span` y realizará la multiplicación, el valor resultante lo agregará a otro `span` que indica el valor total, revisa este ejemplo:

```js
function multiplicar() {

  var subtotal = document.getElementById('sub-total').innerHTML;
  var total = document.getElementById('total').innerHTML;

  var multi = subtotal * total;
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML= multi;  
  
}
```

```html
 
   <body onload="multiplicar()">
    Subtotal:<span id="sub-total">5</span><br>
    Total:<span id="total">10</span><br>
    <hr>
    Resultado:<span id="resultado"></span><br>
```